# Why did Jest encounter unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am new to Jest testing and I wrote a small user.test.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('../models/User');
const userData = { username: 'TekLoon', email: 'jon@aol.com' };

describe('User Model Test', () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await mongoose.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
    });

    it('create & save user successfully', async () => {
        const validUser = new UserModel(userData);
        const savedUser = await validUser.save();
        // Object Id should be defined when successfully saved to MongoDB.
        expect(savedUser._id).toBeDefined();
        expect(savedUser.username).toBe(userData.username);
        expect(savedUser.email).toBe(userData.email);
    });
});
```

Directory structure

```
globalConfig.json
index.js
models
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
__tests__
```

When I run npm run test

```
FAIL  .history/__tests__/user.test_20201027153457.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    Details:

SyntaxError: /home/milenko/pract/post/.history/__tests__/user.test_20201027153457.js: Unexpected token (26:7)

  24 |         expect(savedUser.username).toBe(userData.username);
  25 |         expect(savedUser.email).toBe(userData.email);
> 26 |     });
         |        ^
```

I followed Christian's advice,problems are again here

```
 FAIL  __tests__/jest-mongodb-config.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)

 FAIL  __tests__/jest.config.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)
```

I will add image to highlight
[image]

Comma expected?

How to fix this?

Comment: You seem to miss at least two parenthesis, on for the `describe` block and one for `beforeAll`

Comment: @Christian Take a look at my edit,please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add closing parenthesis for `describe` and `beforeAll`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('../models/User');
const userData = { username: 'TekLoon', email:'jon@aol.com' };

describe('User Model Test', () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await mongoose.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }) // added closing parenthesis

    it('create & save user successfully', async () => {
        const validUser = new UserModel(userData);
        const savedUser = await validUser.save();
        // Object Id should be defined when successfully saved to MongoDB.
        expect(savedUser._id).toBeDefined();
        expect(savedUser.username).toBe(userData.username);
        expect(savedUser.email).toBe(userData.email);
    });
}); // added closing parenthesis
```

Comment: Thanks,anyway I have similiar problems again.

Comment: There's still a syntax error somewhere. Please update your code in the question in accordance with suggested edits. Also, change the `connect` call to not use a mix of `await` and callback style:   
`try {`
    `await mongoose.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });`
`} catch(err) {`
    `console.error(err);`
    `process.exit(1);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. Compilers behaviour was somehow misleading. The solution was to put
`jest.config.js` with this content

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
};
```

and jest-mongodb-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    instance: {
      dbName: 'jest'
    },
    binary: {
      version: '4.4.1', 
      skipMD5: true
    },
    autoStart: false
  }
};
```

in PROJECT directory( **tests** is reserved only for test files).
Works fine now(simple example)

```
tests__/user.test.js
  User Model Test
    ✓ create & save user successfully (19 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.895 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.
```